# Cluster text keeping the continuity of the text

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am looking for a way to cluster a big text (hundreds of pages) at a paragraph level, but keeping the continuity of the text intact. In other words, this sums up into clustering the text into chapters. Can someone provide me with a starting point at how to do this?

Researching this a bit, didn't find anything relevant to my problem, but more on the task of clustering either individual paragraphs as independent ones or clustering file titles etc.

Any idea or link that would point me to the right direction would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: What is the data format for your text? How do you identify paragraphs in your data format? What kind of clustering do you need? What kind of metrics do you consider to group by clusters? And so on.... So much info missing in your question! Machine learning is not magic, it's just some data processing done with some adapted tools

Comment: Doing a little more research I found that what I was looking for is called `text segmentation` and is not referred as clustering. I am trying at this moment to achieve this and will leave a reply with sources if I will succeed. Feel free to leave any relevant links for this related topic :).